# Shell Extension DLL - how to capture the folder path, if user clicks inside the folder empty area?

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions

Using shell extension dll, how to capture the folder path, if user clicks inside the folder empty area?

Comment: Did you try calling [GetCurrentDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @dario_ramos: Wrong function. On _some_ systems, there's one Explorer process for all Explorer windows. If you have two windows open on two different folders, `GetCurrentDir` can't return _both_. (If you've enabled "Open new window in separate process", then it could work. Not guaranteed though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're implementing a shell extension dll, then you get the path in your [IShellExtInit::Initialize(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775094.aspx)) method as the `pidlFolder` parameter.

To make sure your extension is also registered for folder backgrounds, you have to create the appropriate entries also under `HKCR\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`

Comment: If we click inside a folder  ie, empty area then "pidlFolder" will be  NULL

Comment: Not in my shell extensions. pidlFolder is not NULL when right-clicking on a folder background (empty area).

Comment: But there is an issue, if I use pidlFolder for getting the path, QueryContextMenu function is not hiiting.

Comment: you have to register your extension for the background.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can use `SHGetPathFromIDList` to turn this pidlFolder into a path string.

Answer (score 0):

With VC++ language please reference Winmerge souce code
http://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ShellExtension/

With C# please reference this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang
and update some place bellow:
At FileContextMenuExt.cs file:

...............

```
    #region Shell Extension Registration

    [ComRegisterFunction()]
    public static void Register(Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            ShellExtReg.RegisterShellExtContextMenuHandler(t.GUID, "Directory", 
                "CSShellExtContextMenuHandler.FileContextMenuExt Class");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Log the error
            throw;  // Re-throw the exception
        }
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction()]
    public static void Unregister(Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            ShellExtReg.UnregisterShellExtContextMenuHandler(t.GUID, "Directory");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Log the error
            throw;  // Re-throw the exception
        }
    }

    #endregion
   ............... 

   public void Initialize(IntPtr pidlFolder, IntPtr pDataObj, IntPtr hKeyProgID)
    {
        if (pDataObj == IntPtr.Zero && pidlFolder == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        FORMATETC fe = new FORMATETC();
        fe.cfFormat = (short)CLIPFORMAT.CF_HDROP;
        fe.ptd = IntPtr.Zero;
        fe.dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT;
        fe.lindex = -1;
        fe.tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        STGMEDIUM stm = new STGMEDIUM();          

        try
        {
            if (pDataObj != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // The pDataObj pointer contains the objects being acted upon. In this 
                // example, we get an HDROP handle for enumerating the selected files 
                // and folders.
                IDataObject dataObject = (IDataObject)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(pDataObj);
                dataObject.GetData(ref fe, out stm);

                // Get an HDROP handle.
                IntPtr hDrop = stm.unionmember;
                if (hDrop == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }

                // Determine how many files are involved in this operation.
                uint nFiles = NativeMethods.DragQueryFile(hDrop, UInt32.MaxValue, null, 0);

                // This code sample displays the custom context menu item when only 
                // one file is selected. 
                if (nFiles == 1)
                {
                    // Get the path of the file.
                    StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder(260);
                    if (0 == NativeMethods.DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0, fileName,
                        fileName.Capacity))
                    {
                        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(WinError.E_FAIL);
                    }
                    this.selectedFile = fileName.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(WinError.E_FAIL);
                }
            }

            if (pidlFolder != IntPtr.Zero) {
                StringBuilder folderName = new StringBuilder(260);
                if (0 == NativeMethods.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlFolder, folderName))
                {
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(WinError.E_FAIL);
                }
                this.selectedFile = folderName.ToString();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            NativeMethods.ReleaseStgMedium(ref stm);
        }
    }
```

At ShellExtLib.cs file Add folowing source:

```
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SHGetPathFromIDList(
        IntPtr pidl,                // Address of an item identifier list that
        // specifies a file or directory location
        // relative to the root of the namespace (the
        // desktop). 
        StringBuilder pszPath);        // Address of a buffer to receive the file system
```

And update RegisterShellExtContextMenuHandler and UnregisterShellExtContextMenuHandler function at ShellExtLib.cs file

```
    public static void RegisterShellExtContextMenuHandler(Guid clsid, 
        string fileType, string friendlyName)
    {
        if (clsid == Guid.Empty)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("clsid must not be empty");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("fileType must not be null or empty");
        }

        // If fileType starts with '.', try to read the default value of the 
        // HKCR\<File Type> key which contains the ProgID to which the file type 
        // is linked.
        if (fileType.StartsWith("."))
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(fileType))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    // If the key exists and its default value is not empty, use 
                    // the ProgID as the file type.
                    string defaultVal = key.GetValue(null) as string;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultVal))
                    {
                        fileType = defaultVal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {

            // Create the key HKCR\<File Type>\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{<CLSID>}.
            string keyName1 = string.Format(@"{0}\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{1}",
                fileType, clsid.ToString("B"));
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(keyName1))
            {
                // Set the default value of the key.
                if (key != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(friendlyName))
                {
                    key.SetValue(null, friendlyName);
                }
            }
        }

        // Create the key HKCR\<File Type>\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{<CLSID>}.
        string keyName = string.Format(@"{0}\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{1}",
            fileType, clsid.ToString("B"));
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(keyName))
        {
            // Set the default value of the key.
            if (key != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(friendlyName))
            {
                key.SetValue(null, friendlyName);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void UnregisterShellExtContextMenuHandler(Guid clsid, 
        string fileType)
    {
        if (clsid == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("clsid must not be null");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("fileType must not be null or empty");
        }

        // If fileType starts with '.', try to read the default value of the 
        // HKCR\<File Type> key which contains the ProgID to which the file type 
        // is linked.
        if (fileType.StartsWith("."))
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(fileType))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    // If the key exists and its default value is not empty, use 
                    // the ProgID as the file type.
                    string defaultVal = key.GetValue(null) as string;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultVal))
                    {
                        fileType = defaultVal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Remove the key HKCR\<File Type>\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{<CLSID>}.
            string keyName1 = string.Format(@"{0}\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{1}",
                fileType, clsid.ToString("B"));
            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree(keyName1, false);
        }

        // Remove the key HKCR\<File Type>\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{<CLSID>}.
        string keyName = string.Format(@"{0}\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{1}",
            fileType, clsid.ToString("B"));
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree(keyName, false);
    }
```